# How Do I Make Poker Winnings look like Normal Income

Tags: poker-theory, poker-tools

So recently I have been on a huge run winning tons of money in offline cash games. I am making so much a month I want to quit my job and just play poker full time and take rest of day off, pay all appropriate taxes and so forth

The catch is I am married with a somewhat nosey husband. I cant fake a Small Business with said poker winnings plugged in. So any ideas on how to make it appear like I am earning a normal monthly paycheck (the Company does not matter) to my husband. Taxes are ez since I file them and I just report the income according to standard IRS Regulations. Thoughts.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure relationship or financial advice is on topic here...

Comment: Yeah but its related to Poker

Comment: Does your husband not support your poker playing? Does he even know about it? What are your plans for when you start running cold? Is your bankroll big enough for the stakes you play? There are a lot of questions that need to be answered before you should even consider playing professionally.

Comment: I have a good sized roll that if I hit 87% a month I meet my expenses. I know I will go cold at some point so I need to build a strategic reserve.

Comment: Substitute "cash games" and the word poker for anything that makes money and its obvious its only vaguely about poker in the scope of the site. It's just very broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was going to write this as a comment reply, but as it's probably the best answer you are going to get I'm going to go ahead and post it as such.

You basically want to hide your source of income from your husband.  The only way I see that it relates to poker is that the cash is actually coming from a casino that has live poker.  Aside from the relationship and financial questions this raises, it sounds like what you are asking if how you can appear to be receiving income that is actually coming from a casino setting as if it were a job.

Hypothetically speaking, if you were to hold on to your chips between sessions and only cash out the excess (i.e. only the winnings and not your base bankroll and some excess) every couple of weeks, you would probably have a large enough amount that the casino would probably be okay with cutting you a check and reporting your winnings to the IRS.  As long as they are cash (not tournament) chips I don't think any casino would mind you doing this, as you are essentially giving them an interest free loan while you hold the chips.  Because you would be receiving a check on what appeared to be a regular paycheck basis, to someone not looking too closely into it might look like a pay check.

As such, you might be able to make it look like (or pass it off as if) you are actually employed by the casino.   In fact, if you present it right, you would not even have to lie about it; "I got a job at the casino" is true, from a certain perspective, if you are a professional poker player you do in fact work at casinos, at the poker table.  You would also not have any issues about lying about where you are.    If your husband is okay thinking you work *for* a casino, then over time you can also transition him to thinking favorably about the idea that you are working *at* a casino but not for a casino.  For instance, you might from time to time come home with extra money that you "won" after work.  "Hey, I discovered this game and that I'm pretty good at it, I think if I did this full time I could make more than my current income!"  (Of course you could also just go ahead and do that *now* without the whole charade, but maybe it takes a while to warm him up to the idea.)  If he becomes favorable to the idea, then you can transition to the idea that you are now going to be making money playing poker and not actually working at a casino. (Note: I'm not sure the policies of employees playing in their own casinos if there isn't more than one close by, but then again, maybe your husband doesn't either!)

You are of course not going to have a regular income.  If you are making enough this should not be a problem.  If you consistently on average make more than the regular amount you want to appear to be making, then cash out that amount every two weeks, and keep the rest in chips as your bankroll to absorbs the ups and downs as they come.

This also won't work if your husband doesn't like the idea of working at a casino.  I don't know what your regular job is or what kind of work your husband might expect you to be doing, but there are plenty of jobs in the hotel portion of a casino that you might imply you are working if the casino part is unsavory to him.

But please, also consider the relationship and financial questions that are raised before taking any of this theoretical discussion to implementation.  It would be very unfortunate if you hit an extended downswing and had to "lose" your job at the casino because your bankroll got wiped out and could leave to some difficult conversations.

Comment: Wow what a great response. Thanks. The book I play at does issue checks and I am fairly discipline at absorbing ups and downs. Internet Poker is a little harder than in person cash games thought so ill need a big reserve. In person cash games vs men are really quite easy, most male players (non-pro) are easy to clock and distractible. A short skirt and hot female date throws them off and me into profits! Thanks